# subversion report?

Tags: svn, reporting

Is there a good (free) way to generate simple subversion reports on a Windows system?  The report I have in mind is ... what commits have been made by user X in the past Y days, showing commit comment and timestamp, sorted chronologically, broken out by day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/)?
I think it comes close to what you are looking for. From their website:

> StatSVN retrieves information from a
>   Subversion repository and generates
>   various tables and charts describing
>   the project development, e.g.
>
> ```
> * Timeline for the lines of code
> * Lines of code for each developer
> * Activity by Clock time
> * Authors Activity
> * Author activity per Module
> * Author Most Recent Commits with links to ViewVc
> * Stats per directory
> * File count
> * Average file size
> * Largest files
> * Files with most revisions
> * Directory Sizes
> * Repository Tags Number of LOC per version.
> * Repository tree with file count and lines of code
> * LOC and Churn the evolution of LOC and the amount of change per day
> * Repo Map the dynamic hierarchical view of your repo for the last 30 days
> ```

Answer (score 0):

arent show log and some [features](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/help-onepage.html#tsvn-dug-showlog-5) provided by [tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) enough?

Comment: I want a single document that I can cut and paste into a status report... Tortoise makes me cut and paste each commit separately